# How do I delete an instance from a class by method in python?

Tags: oop

The problem I'm facing is that I have `person_1` Instance
And I create a `destroyed` static method that should delete any instance
That passed to it as y parameter but the instance still exists.

[image]

I want `person_1` to be removed and python should give an error message.

Thanks in advance

```
class population:
    """ This class is used 
    To adds and delete people """

    x = 0 

    def __init__(self,name): 
        self.name = name
        print(f'Initilaizing {name}\n Total_persons. {population.x}')

        population.x += 1  

    @classmethod
    # This class method is used to adds a new instance to the population class.
    def constructor(cls, y):
        population.x += 1 
        return cls(y)

    @staticmethod
    # This static method is used to remove an instance from the population class. 
    def destroyed(k): 
        del k
        population.x -= 1
        print(f'Total_persons after destroyed procedure. {population.x}')


person_1 = population('mohammed')
print(person_1.name)

population.destroyed(person_1)

print(person_1.name)
```

Comment: Is there any particlar reason why you want to do it this way?
In standard OOP, you would have instances of class propulation which are then added in a datastructure (list, array) in other code areas so for instance, country which has an instance variable of population which contains entries of class population.
You remove population by removing an instance from the list.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're running into is caused by the fact that `del k` in your destroyed function is killing off only that instance of the object, not the one outside of the function scope. Python allows you to add functionality to a deleting an object with the `__del__` function.

Implementing as such:

```
    def __del__(self):
        population.x -= 1
        print(f'Total_persons after destroyed procedure. {population.x}')
```

Will allow you to replace `population.destroyed(person_1)` with `del person_1` to get the result you're looking for.